# organizing a messy txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
0.147E-01-0.158E-01-0.707E-02 0.173E-01
-0.593E-01 0.111E+00 0.153E+00 0.155E+00
0.859E-01-0.664E-01-0.281E+00-0.497E+00
-0.626E+00-0.587E+00-0.347E+00 0.560E-01
```

This is a very long file, so I can't do it manually.
As you can see some of the numbers have spaces between them, and others (negative values) don't.
When I'm trying to read it, I can't find a proper way to separate the values.
If I choose delimiter='-', my script reads the values that have spaces between them as one value.
If I choose delimiter=' ', my script does the same thing to the values saprated with minos.
Is there a good wey to read the text and to be able to separate the values well?

my script:

```
inf=open("data","r")
for columns in ( raw.strip().split() for raw in inf ):
    print (columns[0])
```

Answer (score 7):

It's not the most optimal solution but try out this:

```
normalized_file_content = file_content.replace('-', ' -').replace('E -', 'E-')
```

This will add a space before the negative numbers but not between the `E` and `-` sign.

Comment: Something like this: `for columns in ( raw.strip().split() for raw in inf.replace('-', ' -').replace('E -', 'E-') ):`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using regex

```
for row in data:
    print map(float, re.findall('-?\d\.\d{3}E[+-]\d{2}', row)
```